# How to make a dictionary with two lists and index of lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two parallel lists of data like:

```
genres = ["classic", "pop", "classic", "classic", "pop"]
plays = [500, 600, 150, 800, 2500]
```

I want to get this result:

```
album = {"classic":{0:500, 2:150, 3:800}, "pop":{1:600, 4:2500}} # want to make
```

So I tried this code:

```
    album = dict.fromkeys(genres,dict())
    # album = {'classic': {}, 'pop': {}}

    for i in range(len(genres)):
        for key,value in album.items():
            if genres[i] == key:
                album[key].update({i:plays[i]})
```

The result for `album` is wrong. It looks like

```
{'classic': {0: 500, 1: 600, 2: 150, 3: 800, 4: 2500},
 'pop': {0: 500, 1: 600, 2: 150, 3: 800, 4: 2500}}
```

That is, every `plays` value was added for both of the genres, instead of being added only to the genre that corresponds to the number.

Why does this occur? How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `album = dict.fromkeys(genres,dict())` with

```py
album = {genre: {} for genre in genres}
```

The reason why your `dict.fromkeys` does not work is documented in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

> `fromkeys()` is a class method that returns a new dictionary. *value* defaults to `None`. All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for *value* to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead.

That is, when you write `album = dict.fromkeys(genres,dict())`, `album['classic']` and `album['pop']` both are the *same* object. As you add new items to either one of them, it is applied to the other (because they are the same object).

---

Alternatively, you can use `defaultdict` and `zip`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

genres = ["classic", "pop", "classic", "classic", "pop"]
plays = [500, 600, 150, 800, 2500]

album = defaultdict(dict)
for i, (genre, play) in enumerate(zip(genres, plays)):
    album[genre][i] = play

print(dict(album))
# {'classic': {0: 500, 2: 150, 3: 800}, 'pop': {1: 600, 4: 2500}}
```

The `dict(album)` is redundant in most cases; you can use `album` like a dict.

Comment: The `zip` trick is just a way to make the loop nicer - it would be equally applicable if `album` were created via the dict comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
In [1059]: d = {}

In [1060]: for c,i in enumerate(genres):
      ...:     if i in d:
      ...:         d[i].update({c:plays[c]})
      ...:     else:
      ...:         d[i] = {c:plays[c]}
      ...: 

In [1061]: d
Out[1061]: {'classic': {0: 500, 2: 150, 3: 800}, 'pop': {1: 600, 4: 2500}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here: first off, the `for key,value in album.items():` loop is redundant, although this will not cause a problem because dictionaries have unique keys - you will store every key-value pair twice, but the second time will just replace the first.

The important problem is that after `album = dict.fromkeys(genres,dict())`, the two values in `album` will be **the same** dictionary. `dict()` happens *before* the call to `dict.fromkeys`, and the resulting object is passed in. `dict.fromkeys()` uses that *same object* as the value for each key - it does *not* make a copy.

To solve this, use a dict comprehension to create the dictionary instead:

```
album = {g: {} for g in genres}
```

This is an analogous problem to [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178), except that instead of a list-of-lists it is a dict-with-dict values, and instead of creating the problematic data by multiplication we create it with a method. The underlying logic is the same, however, and the natural solution works in the same way as well.

Another approach is to create the key-value pairs in `album` only when they are first needed, by checking for their presence first.

Yet another approach is to use a tool that automates that on-demand creation - for example, `defaultdict` from the standard library `collections` module`. That way looks like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
# other code until we get to:
album = defaultdict(dict)
# whenever we try `album[k].update(v)`, if there is not already an
# `album[k]`, it will automatically create `album[k] = dict()` first
# - with a new dictionary, created just then.
```

Answer (score 0):

@j1-lee answered it correctly, but just in case you want to avoid defaultdict and go with primitive dictionary here is the code.

```
genres = ["classic", "pop", "classic", "classic", "pop"]
plays = [500, 600, 150, 800, 2500]

all_genres_plays = zip(genres, plays)
album = {}
for index, single_genre_play in enumerate(all_genres_plays):
    genre, play = single_genre_play
    if genre not in album:
        album[genre] = {}
    album[genre][index] = play

print(album)
```

output:

```
{'classic': {0: 500, 2: 150, 3: 800}, 'pop': {1: 600, 4: 2500}}
```